# The Process of Clearing and Redrawing a Square on a HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript

I have been working on some HTML/Javascript Code and the main thing I want to have happen is when you press any of the arrow keys, the square that I drew moves that direction.

My general train of thought on what I have to do, is when I click on the key, it first clears the canvas, then redraws it with a different x and y value based on the function.

I tried that, but what happens is that the square just vanishes and I have no clue why.

I have been attempting to debug this for a while, and if anyone has any pointers I would love to here them!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
    <title> HTML </title>
    <style>
        canvas {
            border: 1px solid #000000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <canvas width = "620" height = "620" id = "myCanvas" ></canvas>
    </center>
    <script src = "script.js" > </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the Javascript Code (Sorry for not well formatting, still getting the hang of formatting code in StackOverflow)

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
if(event.keyCode == 37) 
    moveLeft();
if(event.keyCode == 39 )
    moveRight();
if(event.keyCode == 38) 
    moveUp();
if(event.keyCode == 40)
    moveDown();
});

 function moveLeft() {
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

//Edit X and Y Values

var newX, newY;
newX = squareX + 1;
newY = squareY;

context.rect(newX, newY, squareSizeX, squareSizeY);
context.fill(newX, newY, squareSizeX, squareSizeY);
}

function moveRight() {/* Needs to be Finished */}

function moveUp() {/* Needs to be Finished */}

function moveDown() {/* Needs to be Finished */}



var canvas;
var context;

var squareX, squareY;

var squareSizeX = 75;
var squareSizeY = 75;

function renderToCanvas() {
    var didRender = false;

try {
    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    /* INPUT DRAWING HERE */

    //Drawing Square

    squareX = canvas.width / 2;
    squareY = canvas.height / 2;

    context.rect(squareX, squareY, squareSizeX, squareSizeY);
    context.fillRect(squareX, squareY, squareSizeX, squareSizeY);
    context.stroke();

    /* END DRAWING HERE */

    didRender = true;
    console.log("Rendered Drawing: " + didRender);
}

catch(err) {
    console.log("Rendered Drawing: " + didRender);
    console.log(err.message);
    }
}


renderToCanvas();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `moveLeft` instead of this

```
context.rect(newX, newY, squareSizeX, squareSizeY);
context.fill(newX, newY, squareSizeX, squareSizeY);
```

Do this

`context.fillRect(newX, newY, squareSizeX, squareSizeY);`

[Check out the docs for Canvas Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D)

You only use `context.rect()` or `context.fill()` when you are working on a path using `context.beginPath()`

Comment: It worked. However, I encountered another problem with it. Whenever I press left again, it does not run again? Do you think it is a problem with the action / key listener?

Comment: It is because you are not updating the x coordinate accordingly, it is still running, but the new x is not updating so it looks like it just stays still

Comment: Yeah, i just figured out that it is still running, thanks!